# JSvalidator for Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

How can I use JSvalidator like [proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation](https://github.com/proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation)
in backpack?

I know that you can edit the request rules for validation, but that's not what I want. I want a field to be validated onchange, onkeyup and etc. and JSvalidator libraries can help me big, instead of doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a hack... but it works. What I did when I needed extra JS in my operations (in your case Create&Update) is that I [created a Backpack Widget](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/base-widgets#creating-a-custom-widget-type) that will include the extra JS I need. And then I use that widget on those operations. This translates to something like a `product_validation.php` file:

```php
@push('after_scripts')
    <script>
      // your custom code here
    </script>
@endpush
```

and then doing:

```php
public function setupCreateOperation() {
        Widget::add()
            ->to('after_content')
            ->type('product_validation')
            ->content(null);
}
```